# Get the mouse-clicked position relative to control within OnClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this bulletedlist:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BLLinks" runat="server" Width="100%" 
BulletStyle="CustomImage" BulletImageUrl="~/Images/link.png" 
OnClick="BLLinks_Click" ></asp:BulletedList>
```

I need to get the position relative to the bulletedlist item where the user clicked in this event:

```
protected void BLLinks_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
   // check the clicked position in the bulleted list
   // if on the bulleted list image do so and so...
   // if on the bulleted list item text do so and so....

}
```

Comment: There is a way to get the (x,y) position of the mouse with client code and store it in a hidden field. However, the click will not trigger a postback unless the BulletedList has `DisplayMode="LinkButton"`. I don't know if the mouse coordinates would still be useful in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse position with client code and store it in a hidden field.

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenMouseXY" runat="server" />
<asp:BulletedList onmousedown="bulletedListMouseDown(this, event);" ... >
    ...
</asp:BulletedList>
```

And the Javascript function:

```
function bulletedListMouseDown(lst, evt) {
    var x = evt.pageX - lst.offsetLeft;
    var y = evt.pageY - lst.offsetTop; 
    var coord = "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y;
    alert(coord);
    document.getElementById('hiddenMouseXY').value = coord;
}
```

If you want the click to trigger a postback, you can call `__doPostBack` in the Javascript function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i will give that a try as soon as i can